# Inputting dates from python to a database

Tags: python, sql, date

I have the following query in which i'm trying to pass start dates and end dates in a sql query.

```
def get_data(start_date,end_date):

    ic = Connector()
    q = f"""
    select * from example_table a 
    
    where a.date between {start_date} and {end_date}

    """
    result = ic.query(q)
    return result

df = pd.DataFrame(get_data('2021-01-01','2021-01-31'))
print(df)
```

which leads to the following error:

```
AnalysisException: Incompatible return types 'STRING' and 'BIGINT' of exprs 'a.date' and '2021 - 1 - 1'.\n (110) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

I have also tried to parse the dates as follows:

```
 import datetime 
 start_date = datetime.date(2021,1,1)
 end_date = datetime.date(2021,5,13)
 df = pd.DataFrame(get_data(start_date,end_date))
```

but i still get the same error.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me, that it is because how you inject your values into sql query they don't get recognized as date values. Database will likely `2021-01-01` interpret as mathematical expression with `2019` being the result.

You should try put parentheses around your values.

```py
    q = f"""
    select * from example_table a 
    where a.date between '{start_date}' and '{end_date}'
    """
```

Or preferably if your db library allows it don't inject your values directly

```py
    q = """
    select * from example_table a 
    where a.date between %s and %s
    """
    result = ic.query(q, (start_date, end_date))
```

**EDIT**: Some database libraries may use place-holder with different format than `%s`. You should probably consult documentation of db library you are using.